# Search a certain value in multiple dataframes and storage records

Tags: r, dataframe, count, nested-loops

I believe this one is a complex problem and I will try to make it easy to understand.

I have 3 dataframes such as:

```
NS_3<-as.data.frame(cbind(c("3","3","3","3","3"),c("341007","325001","324003","524302","346002")))
NS_4<-as.data.frame(cbind(c("4","4","4","4","4","4","4"),c("341007","270001","270001","521009","346001","524302","335104")))

NS_15<-as.data.frame(cbind(c("15","15","15","15","15"),c("301001","301001","316104","344003","291003")))

names(NS_3)<-c("NS", "Pred FAILCODE TEST")
names(NS_4)<-c("NS", "Pred FAILCODE TEST")
names(NS_15)<-c("NS", "Pred FAILCODE TEST")
```

[image of the three dataframes](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Uct5A.png)

What I would like to do is to:

1) Check if dataframes `NS_4` and `NS_15` contain the values of each row of `NS_3$Pred FAILCODE TEST`.

2) If this value is present in a certain dataframe, then it should count and storage all the values of the `Pred FAILCODE TEST`of this dataframe, except for the value found.

For instance:
For the first `Pred FAILCODE TEST` value in `NS_3`, check if `341007` is present in `NS_4` and `NS_15`.

Once this check is `TRUE` in `NS_4`, then it should count the frequency of all the `NS_4$Pred FAILCODE TEST` values, except for the one in question (which is `341007`).

Hence, the result for the first loop should be

[Results for the first loop 341007](https://i.stack.imgur.com/V5OY4.png)

For the second and third value of `NS_3$Pred FAILCODE TEST`, as neither `325001` nor `324003` appear at any dataframe, they should not be considered.

For the fourth value `524302`, the result should be something like:

```
FAILCODES 524302
341007    1
270001    2
521009    1
346001    1
335104    1
```

Once the loop ends with `NS_3$Pred FAILCODE TEST` values, then it should do the same thing to `NS_4$Pred FAILCODE TEST` values, searching them in `NS_3` and `NS_15`. After done with NS_4, it should do the same with `NS_15`, searching the 
`NS_15$Pred FAILCODE TEST` values at `NS_3` and `NS_4`.

I believe it will require nested ***for-loops*** to go through each row of each dataframe. Also, `dflist<-list(df1=NS_3,df2=NS_4,df3=NS_15)` would be probably helpful in those loops.

Actually I have around 70 different dataframes and 50 different `Pred FAILCODE TEST` values to check in each dataframe.

I hope it is clear, if you guys need more infos please let me know!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Think this does it,

```
#your code
NS_3<-as.data.frame(cbind(c("3","3","3","3","3"),c("341007","325001","324003","524302","346002")))
NS_4<-as.data.frame(cbind(c("4","4","4","4","4","4","4"),c("341007","270001","270001","521009","346001","524302","335104")))
NS_15<-as.data.frame(cbind(c("15","15","15","15","15"),c("301001","301001","316104","344003","291003")))

names(NS_3)<-c("NS", "Pred FAILCODE TEST")
names(NS_4)<-c("NS", "Pred FAILCODE TEST")
names(NS_15)<-c("NS", "Pred FAILCODE TEST")

#Make a vector of your Tables suffixes
df_index <- c(3,4,15)

#Essentially rbind() all of tables in your df_index 
#there is probably an elegant way to do this with do.call()
input <- eval(parse(text = paste0("rbind(",  
                     paste0("NS_", df_index, collapse = ","), 
                     ")")
       )
 )

require(dplyr)
require(magrittr)

#convert from factor to numeric
input$`Pred FAILCODE TEST` <- as.numeric(as.character(input$`Pred FAILCODE TEST`))
input$NS <- as.numeric(as.character(input$NS))

#make a compressed table of frequencies
input %>% group_by(NS, `Pred FAILCODE TEST`) %>% 
summarize(n=n()) -> compressTBL

#little function to look up each record and compare
Lookup <- function(NS, FailCode){
  input$NS[input$`Pred FAILCODE TEST` == FailCode & !input$NS == NS]
}

#the output, a list, each column is row in your input table
output <- sapply(X = 1:nrow(input), 
   FUN = function(x){
   compressTBL[compressTBL$NS == Lookup(input$NS[x], input$`Pred FAILCODE TEST`[x]),]
   })

#The only records with values are 1,4,6,11
output

#same as what you got in your loop
as.data.frame(output[,4]) #4th record 524302
```

Comment: Great! That is definetely a more clever way to approach than I was thinking. Thank you very much for your answer!